# Python's `collections.Counter` with non-integer values

Tags: python, python-collections

`collections.Counter` is extremely useful to gather counts and operate on counts as objects. You can do things like:

```py
>>> Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 5}) + Counter({'a': 3, 'c': 7})
Counter({'c': 7, 'a': 5, 'b': 5})
```

This essentially groups items by their keys and sums the values of each group.

**What is a minimum-code way to reuse the `Counter` functionality with non-integer values?**

These values would have addition defined to be the group values "reducing" operation I want already: For example strings and lists (which both have `__add__` defined to be concatenation).

As is, we get:

```py
>>> Counter({'a': 'hello ', 'b': 'B'}) + Counter({'a': 'world', 'c': 'C'})
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
>>> Counter({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]}) + Counter({'a': [1, 1], 'c': [5, 6, 7]})
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

In the code of `collections.Counter`, there is a hard-coded assumption that values are integers, and therefore things like `self.get(k, 0)` and `count > 0` littered all over the place. It seems therefore that subclassing `Counter` wouldn't be much less work than rewriting my own specialized (or general) custom class (probably using `collections.defaultdict`).

Instead, it seems like wrapping the values (e.g. `str` and `list`) to be able to operate with 0 as if it were an empty element might be the elegant approach.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: As its name suggests - `Counter` is used for **counting** therefore has no pre-defined behavior for working with strings. As you mentioned yourself, you might be able to get what you're looking for by working with `defaultdict`s instead

Comment: How would `Counter({'a': 'hello ', 'b': 'B'})` even look like? What would be values?

Comment: "What is a minimum-code way to reuse the Counter functionality" _Which_ Counter functionality? Being able to "add" similar elements together? Getting the "most-common" elements? Adding, subtracting and/or comparing Counters? How would those work when concatenating strings or lists?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't call "defining addition to integers for collection types" more elegant than just rewriting `Counter` to do the work you need. You need non-counting related behaviors, you need a class that isn't focused on counting things.

Fundamentally, `Counter` is inappropriate to your use case; you don't have *counts*. What does `elements` mean when you lack a count to multiply each key by? `most_common` might work as written, but it would have nothing to do with frequencies.

In 95% of cases, I'd just use `collections.defaultdict(list)` (or whatever default is appropriate), and in the other 5%, I'd use `Counter` as a model and implement my own version (without count-specific behaviors).

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose two solutions:

One wrapping the values themselves, though only the examples in the question are assured to covered here: Other `Counter` operations are not:

```py
>>> class ZeroAsEmptyMixin:
...     _empty_val = None
...
...     def __gt__(self, other):
...         if isinstance(other, int) and other == 0:
...             other = self._empty_val
...         return super().__gt__(other)
...
...     def __add__(self, other):
...         if isinstance(other, int) and other == 0:
...             other = self._empty_val
...         return self.__class__(super().__add__(other))
...
...
>>> class mystr(ZeroAsEmptyMixin, str):
...     _empty_val = str()
...
...
>>> class mylist(ZeroAsEmptyMixin, list):
...     _empty_val = list()
...
...
>>>
>>> Counter({'a': mystr('hello '), 'b': mystr('B')}) + Counter({'a': mystr('world'), 'c': mystr('C')})
Counter({'a': 'hello world', 'c': 'C', 'b': 'B'})
>>> Counter({'a': mylist([1, 2]), 'b': mylist([3, 4])}) + Counter({'a': mylist([1, 1]), 'c': mylist([5, 6, 7])})
Counter({'c': [5, 6, 7], 'b': [3, 4], 'a': [1, 2, 1, 1]})
```

The other by writing a "Counter-like" custom class, subclassing `defaultdict`, and again, only implementing the `__add__` method.

```py
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> from functools import wraps
>>>
>>> class MapReducer(defaultdict):
...     @wraps(defaultdict.__init__)
...     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
...         super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
...         self._empty_val = self.default_factory()
...
...     def __add__(self, other):
...         if not isinstance(other, self.__class__):
...             return NotImplemented
...         result = self.__class__(self.default_factory)
...         for elem, val in self.items():
...             newval = val + other[elem]
...             if newval != self._empty_val:
...                 result[elem] = newval
...         for elem, val in other.items():
...             if elem not in self and val != self._empty_val:
...                 result[elem] = val
...         return result
...
...
>>>
>>> strmp = lambda x: MapReducer(str, x)
>>> strmp({'a': 'hello ', 'b': 'B'}) + strmp({'a': 'world', 'c': 'C'})
MapReducer(<class 'str'>, {'a': 'hello world', 'b': 'B', 'c': 'C'})
>>> listmp = lambda x: MapReducer(list, x)
>>> listmp({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]}) + listmp({'a': [1, 1], 'c': [5, 6, 7]})
MapReducer(<class 'list'>, {'a': [1, 2, 1, 1], 'b': [3, 4], 'c': [5, 6, 7]})
```